# How to delete/undefine macros in Context?

Tags: macros, context

How can one delete or undefine macros in Context?
Is there a difference if i've used `\def` or `\define` to create a macro?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why do you want to do 'undefine' a macro? Depending on what you want, try:

```
\let\macro\undefined
```

or

```
\let\macro\donothing
```

It does not matter whether you used `\def` or `\define`

Comment: Note that the first is canonical Tex from Knuth (except that he uses the equals sign: `\let\macro=\undefined`) and is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: The second (`\donothing` is just a more descriptive synonym of `\relax`) is better if you do not want code that uses `\macro` to fail. I am guessing that the OP wants to ignore some ConTeXt environments, `\startsomething` ... `\stopsomething`. In that case, it is better to set them to `\donothing` rather than `\undefined`.

Comment: @CharlesStewart, @Aditya Doesn’t that rely on the fact that `\undefined` is indeed undefined itself? – And isn’t `\@undefined` used for that at so many other places?

Comment: @RobertSiemer: `\@undefined` is used in LaTeX. ConTeXt only uses `\undefined`. In fact, `\undefined` is used about 120 times in the ConTeXt MkIV source files.

Comment: @RobertSiemer - It does rely on `\undefined` having the usual meaning of being undefined.  It also depends on `\let` having the usual meaning of the Tex primitive, and the relevant catcodes being what you expect.  Tex doesn't offer much in the way of safety precautions.