# How can I wipe TeX's memory of a user-defined control sequence?

Tags: macros, errors

I know I can redefine a control sequence to be empty or `\relax`, as in my example below. However, doing so doesn't prevent one from using that control sequence , because it is still defined.

To add some safeguards in my code, I'd like to wipe TeX's memory of a user-defined control sequence, so that, if I subsequently use that control sequence, I get the usual `Undefined control sequence` error. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\foo{foo}
\renewcommand\foo{}
\foo % no error
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\let\foo\undefined`

Comment: So simple, yet I didn't know about it. Thanks. Let's wait to see if my question is a duplicate. Otherwise, you should post an answer.

Comment: related to (but not a duplicate of) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/how-to-delete-undefine-macros-in-context

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is to bind the macro to something which is not defined.
Traditionally, the macro `\undefined` is left undefined (!) so you can simply do

```
\let\foo\undefined
```

If, for some (probably wrong) reason you or some package defines `\undefined` then this trick won't work.

In any case, if you later want to manually check whether `\foo` is defined or not, you can use LaTeX's `\@ifundefined` test which will detect whether `\foo` is undefined *OR* `\relax`.

Comment: Yes, there's no `\undef` primitive. There's `\undef` in `etoolbox`, but it relies on the same method: it does `\let\foo\etb@undefined`, trusting that `\etb@undefined` remains globally undefined.